# Storing a lua class with parent in luabind::object

Tags: c++, scripting, garbage-collection, lua, luabind

Using **C++**, **lua 5.1**, **luabind 0.7-0.81**

Trying to create a lua class with parent and store it in a luabind::object.

**Lua**

```
class 'TestClassParent'
function TestClassParent:__init()
    print('parent init\n')
end
function TestClassParent:__finalize()
    print('parent finalize\n')
end

class 'TestClass' (TestClassParent)
function TestClass:__init()
    print('init\n')
    TestClassParent.__init(self)
end
function TestClass:__finalize()
    print('finalize\n')
end
```

**C++**

```
{
    luabind::object obj = luabind::call_function<luabind::object>(lua_state, "TestClass");
}
printf("before GC\n");
lua_gc(lua, LUA_GCCOLLECT, 0);
printf("after GC\n");
```

**Output**:
init
parent init
before GC
after GC

**Result:** After obj is destroyed, 'TestClass' instance is still alive after garbage collection cycle (__finalize method is not called and memory is not freed). It's destroying only on program exit.
**Moresome** if I use class without parent, garbage is collected correctly.

If I try to use **adopt policy** (to take ownership of created object)

```
luabind::object obj = luabind::call_function<luabind::object>(lua_state, "TestClass")[luabind::adopt(luabind::result)];
```

I get:

- in **luabind 0.7** - same result as without adopt policy
- in **luabind 0.81** - crash with message "you are trying to use an unregistrerd type"

How can I correctly **create a lua object in C++** and **take it's ownership**?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a known bug in 0.8.1; a reference to the last constructed object is left in the "super" function upvalue. It has been fixed in 0.9-rc1:

http://github.com/luabind/luabind/commit/2c99f0475afea7c282c2e432499fd22aa17744e3

Comment: Is this about problem described here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946465/luabind-class-deriving-problem-memory-leak ?

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: after OP's update, this answer is no longer relevant, I'll leave it hanging here though. Daniel Wallin posted the correct answer

*not really an answer, but I'd lose the formatting with a comment*

I cannot reproduce this one. Here's the exact code I use:

```
// initialization
lua_State* lua = lua_open();
luaL_openlibs(lua);
luabind::open(lua);
// declare class
luaL_loadstring(lua, 
    "class 'TestClass'\
     function TestClass:__init() print('init') end\
     function TestClass:__finalize() print('finalize') end");
lua_pcall(lua, 0, LUA_MULTRET, 0);
// instantiate
{
    luabind::object obj = luabind::call_function<luabind::object>(lua, "TestClass");
}
// collect
printf("Before GC collect\n");
lua_gc(lua, LUA_GCCOLLECT, 0);
printf("After GC collect\n");
lua_close(lua);
```

And the result I get is:

> ```
> init
> Before GC collect
> finalize
> After GC collect
> ```

---

I'm using lua 5.1.4, luabind 0.81 with VC8 (aka VS2005) SP1

Comment: Thank you very much for test. You're right. My description of a problem was not correct. It's actual only when class has a parent. I've updated a description in main post.