# Luabind class deriving problem (memory 'leak')

Tags: scripting, garbage-collection, lua, luabind

Using **luabind 0.81**

Simple test to illustrate the problem:

**1)**

```
class 'A'
function A:__init()
   print('A init\n')
end
function A:__finalize()
   print('A finalize\n')
end

do
   local obj = A()
end
collectgarbage("collect")
```

**Output:**
A init
A finalize

**2)**

```
class 'A'
function A:__init()
   print('A init\n')
end
function A:__finalize()
   print('A finalize\n')
end

class 'B' (A)
function B:__init()
   A.__init(self)
   print('B init\n')
end
function B:__finalize()
   print('B finalize\n')
end

do
   local obj = B()
end
collectgarbage('collect')
```

**Output:**
A init
B init

**Problem:** Class with parent is not deleted on garbage collection.

How to solve this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Storing a lua class with parent in luabind::object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939864/storing-a-lua-class-with-parent-in-luabindobject-updated). This is the same problem. The `B` instance is left in a "super" upvalue.

Setting the global `super` to `nil` before calling `collectgarbage()` should make the problem go away:

```
class 'A'
function A:__init()
   print('A init\n')
end
function A:__finalize()
   print('A finalize\n')
end

class 'B' (A)
function B:__init()
   A.__init(self)
   print('B init\n')
end
function B:__finalize()
   print('B finalize\n')
end

do
   local obj = B()
   super = nil
end
collectgarbage('collect')
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Specially for solution with "super = nil", because I can't compile luabind0.9rc to test this fix.